# How can I check if field is null or empty in DWT?

Tags: templating, dwt

I'm making a DWT component template that loops multivalued componentlinked components. I want to check if a textfield in a linked component is empty, but it always gives errors. I need to use the Dreamweaver Get extention, because otherwise I can't get to my deepest linked properties:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.AfbeeldingLink" -->

<img  src="@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding")@@" alt="@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding.Metadata.AltTekst")@@" />

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

This works fine. But now I want to check if a property like

```
@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding.Metadata.AltTekst")@@
```

is empty to do something different. How can I do that? This always gives errors:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="StringLength(@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding.Metadata.AltTekst")@@) > 0" -->
```

Like ' a ; is needed'.

Does anybody has an idea ?

Kind regards,
Herman

Answer (score 3):

When calling `TemplateCallable` methods from within Conditions, don't use `@@` . Simply use the method name as :

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Get(...) !=''" -->
```

I had few `TemplateCallable` custom methods implemented as well and the below syntax always worked for checking if the `AltText` field is Empty or NOT

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="GetMetaDataFieldValue(Component.ArticleImage,'AltText') !=''" -->
```

The method `GetMetaDataFieldValue` has return type of `String`and using `!=''` always worked. Note that there is NO space inbetween the single quotes in `!=''` 

The Dreamweaver's `Get()` method's return type is `String` as well.

Comment: I tried this solution, and I got no error, but it gives always TRUE, so the if statement is always executed: <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Link.ExterneLink")!=''" -->

Comment: Is the Field Empty ?

Comment: As a side check -  you can try printing the Field value using @@Get()@@ somewhere else in DWT to see if it really prints/has some value or is Empty

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking checking for empty fields or null values in DWT TBBs means you need to check if the value contains an empty string, so:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding.Metadata.AltTekst")@@ == ''" -->
```

But its been too long for me to remember if the Get extension actually was able to return you empty strings for non existing fields (since when a field is empty, it doesn't have an element in the XML)

You might need to extend the Get extension with a `IsEmpty()` method, which is something I would actually do anyways, since that will clean up your Template code in a great way:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="@@IsEmpty("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Afbeelding.Metadata.AltTekst")@@" -->
```

Well okay not "great", but slightly better, if you want something decent, readable and understandable, I would take a look at [DXA](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/852) and ditch DWT Templating alltogether ;o).

### UPDATE

Good point to mention you got the error when trying to use `@@` inside a condition, now that my memory of DWT Templating is refreshing, I seem to recall there was a limitation we had with custom functions, being that they could not be used in a condition. So looks like my answer will not help you at all, apart from the last bit ;o)

But since I'm digging from memory of years ago (which is likely to be only partially correct), I might still be wrong on this, you could give it a try without the `@@` signs in the condition.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems that if I try to acces a @@ inside a cond, it always gets the error: "; expected".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your help, I finally got it working!

It seems that when my value was empty, the get-function returned 'undefined'. Also, the single quote-solution from above helped, then I got no errors when I surrounded the @@Get@@ with single quotes. The working example is this one:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'@@Get("Fields.AfbeeldingLink[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Fields.Link.ExterneLink")@@'!='undefined'" -->
```

Kind regards and big thanks!
Herman

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just due to missing quotes.

```
StringLength(@@Get("your_field_path")@@)
```

will likely render to:

```
StringLength(This is my field value)
```

This will error since the rendered string isn't in quotes.

Try adding single quotes:

```
StringLength('@@Get("your_field_path")@@')
```

Also you may not even need StringLength, you could probably get away with

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'@@Get("your_field_path")@@'" -->
```

I'll pre-empt a "gotcha".  If your field contains a quote then this will likely break (since you're effectively rendering into a condition then trouble is likely to follow!).